# Neo4j Upsert using apoc procedure

Tags: jdbc, neo4j, neo4j-apoc

I am using apoc.load.jdbc command to connect snowflake and loading data to Neo4j. Is there any way to use the update command if data already exists and insert it if there is no data(like upsert) in neo4j?

```
WITH "jdbc:snowflake://xxxx.xxxx.xxxx.com:xxx/?user=xxxxxxxxxxx&password=xxxxxxxxxxx&db=xxxx&warehouse=xxxx&schema=xxxx" as url CALL apoc.load.jdbc(url,"test_table') YIELD row create (c:test) set c=row
```

Also, is it possible to do an upsert based on Neo4j Label?

Answer (score 1):

I think MERGE is what you are looking for. See https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/merge/